# Proof that $p^{q^p} > q^{p^q}$ for p>q>1 in use of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

Proof that $$p^{q^p} > q^{p^q} $$ for $p>q>1$

### My idea

I am convinced that it can be transformed into inequality wih one additional variable. But firstly we should transform that.

$\ln$ increases so our thesis is true if and only if:
$$ q^p  \ln p > p^q \ln q \\
\ln(q^p  \ln p) > \ln(p^q \ln q) \\
p\ln q+\ln \ln p > q\ln p + \ln \ln q$$
But there I don't know how to transofrm it further. If I could reduce that to 1 variable, then I can make a function and in use of derivatives can solve that problem.

Comment: You're missing some $\ln$'s in the last formula.

Comment: where @RobertIsrael?

Comment: Edited it......

Comment: True, when I back, I will try, but I think that the will be the same problem with $0$ of my function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By your work we need to prove that 
$$p\ln{q}-q\ln{p}+\ln\ln{p}-\ln\ln{q}>0$$ or
$$\ln\frac{\ln{p}}{\ln{q}}>q\ln{p}-p\ln{q},$$ which is obvious for $q\ln{p}-p\ln{q}\leq0.$

Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for $$q\ln{p}>p\ln{q}$$ or
$$\ln{q}+\ln\ln{p}>\ln{p}+\ln\ln{q}$$ or
$$\ln\frac{\ln{p}}{\ln{q}}>\ln{p}-\ln{q}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that $$\ln{p}-\ln{q}>q\ln{p}-p\ln{q}$$ or
$$\frac{p-1}{\ln{p}}>\frac{q-1}{\ln{q}},$$ which is true because $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{\ln{x}}$ increases.

Comment: Is h' in second case correctly calculated?

Comment: @VirtualUser I checked . It seems right. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Because if we treat q as parametr then after take derivative we have -(1/p^2)(q+1/ln(p) + 1/ln^2(p)) but you have q in denominator

Comment: @VirtualUser I used the derivative of $h$  respect to $q$. See please better.

Comment: That's right, I had doubts if we can replace parametr with variable but currently I know that's correct

Comment: @VirtualUser Yes, I just proved that in this case $f'(p)\geq0.$

Comment: can you check if I solved the last step correctly? Let $f$ as you. Then $f'(p) = \ln p - (p/q) + \frac{1}{p \ln p} \geq \ln q - (q/p) + 1/e > 1+(1/e) - (q/p) > 1+ 1/e - 1 = 1/e > 0 $ so f increases. Now $f(e) = e \ln y + 0 - q \ln \ln q  = \ln \frac{q^e}{(\ln q)^q} > \ln \frac{e^e}{(\ln e) ^e} = e > 0 $

Comment: The first step is not true. See please better the definition of f

Comment: Well done, Michael.