# For $ a>b>1$, prove that $a^{b^a}>b^{a^b}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, exponentiation

**Given that $a>b>1$, show that $a^{(b^a)}>b^{(a^b)}$.**

I've proved that the case $b\geq e$ holds as follows:

$$\ln\ln a^{(b^a)}-\ln\ln b^{(a^b)}=a\ln b+\ln\ln a-b\ln a-\ln\ln b$$

Let $t=a-b>0$. Define function 
$$f(t)=(b+t)\ln b+\ln\ln (b+t)-b\ln(b+t)-\ln\ln b$$
By direct computation
$$f'(t)=\frac{g(t)}{(b+t)\ln(b+t)}$$
where $g(t)=\ln b [(b+t)\ln(b+t)]-b\ln(b+t)+1$.

If $b\geq e$, then $g(t)\geq t\ln(b+t)+1>t+1>0$.

And it follows that $f(t)$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and therefore $f(t)\geq f(0)=0$, for all $t>0$.

However, when $b$ is close to $1$, the function $f(t)$ may first increase, then decrease, and eventually increase. And it's hard to estimate the minimum. Having graphed it, I found that that there seemed to be no counterexample.

Is there any inequality or multivariate optimization techniques I can use here?

Comment: It's true for any $a>b>0$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Could you provide a proof or some source?

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324970 and here:     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from an old thread of de.sci.mathematik I participates, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/de.sci.mathematik/hoppe/de.sci.mathematik/Ciz3I81R1Rs/sRJZSiAt1T4J.  It shows that for any two positive numbers $x$ and $y$ it follows that
$$x<y\Rightarrow x^{y^x}<y^{x^y}.$$

It took nearly three weeks in those times to solve the problem. Here we go!

Let $D\subset\mathbb R^2$ and $f\colon D\to\mathbb R$ a real-valued function defined on $D$.  Define $\colon D\to\mathbb R$ by 
$$h(x,y):=f\bigl(x,f(y,x)\bigr).$$
Then if $x<y$ it follows that $h(x,y)<h(y,x)$ if the following (nearly trivial) conditions hold:

(1) $f$ is strictly monotone in its first argument, that is, either $f(y,x)<f(x,y)$ or $f(y,x)>f(x,y)$.

(2) There is a real number $a$ such that $h(x,y)<a<h(y,x)$.

Now $f(x,y):=x^y$, defined for positive $x$ and $y$, satisfies (1) if $1<x<y$ and $y^x<x^y$ or $0<x<y<1$.  The condition (2) is satisfied with $0<x<1<y$ choosing $a=1$.

**Answer to the OP's question:**

The remaining (non-trivial) case is $1<x<y$ and $y^x>x^y$.  In that case there exists a real number $s>1$ with $y=x^s$.  From $y^x>x^y$ we have $sx^{1-s}>1$.

Notice that
$$
x^{y^x}<y^{x^y}\iff x^{sx}<sx^{x^s}.
$$

Now let us invoke Bernoulli, recalling that $x>0$ and $s>1$: as $x^s=\bigl(1+(x-1)\bigr)^s>1+s(x-1)$
we conclude
$$
\frac{sx^{x^s}}{x^{sx}} = sx^{x^s - sx} > sx^{1+s(x - 1)  - sx}= sx^{1 - s} > 1.
$$

Comment: A sufficient condition for $h(s)=g(s)-s=0$ to have a unique solution is $h'(s)=g'(s)-1$ is always positive or is always negative. The case $x>1$ is not well justified: you only showed that $g(s)$ first increases and then decreases, and I don't see this go anywhere. It's hard to write down a counterexample explicitly, but consider the function y=x+0.5sin(x)+0.3, which is always increasing, but yet intersecting the line y=x infinitely many times. For a counterexample, we can modify the original graph by bending it down after the 2nd intersection.

Comment: Your example doesn't provide as a counterexample; think of a downward parabola instead.  Observe that $g$ is a function with one global maximum (for positive $s_0$) and $g(0)>0$ .  How often may $g$ intersect with the identity in that case?

Comment: Yes, a downward parabola is not a counterexample, and it's hard to construct a counterexample using elementary functions. That's why I mentioned the x+sin(x) curve: by modifying it, we can construct a counterexample.

Comment: I remember there was a (minor) flaw; one may show that $g''$ is negative to cure it.  I'll give another prove from the last decade, see my edit, please.

Comment: $sx>x^s$ is equivalent to $sx^{1-s}>1$, not $sx^{s-1}>1$.

Comment: Thanks again, corrected another typo.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITTED SOLUTION**
Consider the function for $b \leq x \leq a$
$$f(x) = x \ln(a+b - x) + \ln(\ln x)$$

$$f'(x) = \ln(a+b - x) + \frac{x}{a+b -x} + \frac{1}{x \ln x}$$

This is an increasing function, as all terms are positive

Hence if $a > b$, then $f(a) > f(b)$

Now, we rewrite that as

$$a\ln b + \ln(\ln a) \gt b\ln a + \ln(\ln b)$$

This will simplify to our original inequality

Comment: The reasoning is great. But I don't see how we can separate the two variables $a$ and $b$. Can you elaborate your idea? If f(x) is increasing, then how can we use it to prove the original inequality?

Comment: Oops, I've made an error, will edit

Comment: The idea is great, but I guess there is something wrong with the 2nd term of your f'(x), you seemed to have forgotten to multiply the derivative of (a+b-x), which means the 2nd term should include a negative sign, and turns out to be negative.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$\ln\ln a-\ln\ln b>b\ln a-a\ln b.$$
Now let
$$y=\ln b>0,\ x=\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}>1.$$
It's sufficient to show that
$$\ln x>y\left(xe^y-e^{xy}\right)\ \ (x>1,y>0).\tag{1}$$
Put $f(x,y)=xe^y-e^{xy}$. Then
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=x\left(e^y-e^{xy}\right)<0.$$
Hence $f$ is decreasing for $y$. Put $t=\frac{\ln x}{x-1}$ to get
$$f(x,t)=0,\ f(x,0)=x-1.$$
(i) If $y\geqslant t$, $yf(x,y)\leqslant 0<\ln x$.

(ii) If $y<t$, $yf(x,y)<tf(x,0)=\ln x$.

Thus the validity of (1) completes the proof.

Comment: It is an excellent solution.